# Connecting bubbles with upward arrows on hover , HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Well let me first of all tell you my problem.

I am building a Bubble chart using HighchartJs library.

I have successfully created the bubble and below is the HighChart.Js code for it

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Task'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            },
         
        },
        yAxis: {
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            
            title: {
                text: 'Months'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            },
            maxPadding: 0.2,
          
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            headerFormat: '<table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>{point.name}</h3></th></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Year:</th><td>{point.x}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Month:</th><td>{point.y}</td></tr>' +
                '<tr><th>Mentions:</th><td>{point.z}</td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            followPointer: true
        },
        

        series: [{
            type: 'bubble',
            name: 'Bubble',
            data: 
            [
                { x: 95, y: 95, z: 13.8, name: 'BE', country: 'Belgium' },
                { x: 86.5, y: 102.9, z: 14.7, name: 'DE', country: 'Germany' },
                { x: 80.8, y: 91.5, z: 15.8, name: 'FI', country: 'Finland' },
                { x: 80.4, y: 102.5, z: 12, name: 'NL', country: 'Netherlands' },
                { x: 80.3, y: 86.1, z: 11.8, name: 'SE', country: 'Sweden' },
                { x: 78.4, y: 70.1, z: 16.6, name: 'ES', country: 'Spain' },
                { x: 74.2, y: 68.5, z: 14.5, name: 'FR', country: 'France' },
                { x: 73.5, y: 83.1, z: 10, name: 'NO', country: 'Norway' },
                { x: 71, y: 93.2, z: 24.7, name: 'UK', country: 'United Kingdom' },
                { x: 69.2, y: 57.6, z: 10.4, name: 'IT', country: 'Italy' },
        { x: 65.1, y: 64.8, z:17.2, name: 'IND', country: 'India'},
                { x: 68.6, y: 20, z: 16, name: 'RU', country: 'Russia' },
                { x: 65.5, y: 126.4, z: 35.3, name: 'US', country: 'United States' },
                { x: 65.4, y: 50.8, z: 28.5, name: 'HU', country: 'Hungary' },
                { x: 63.4, y: 51.8, z: 15.4, name: 'PT', country: 'Portugal' },
                { x: 64, y: 82.9, z: 31.3, name: 'NZ', country: 'New Zealand' }
            ]
    
   }]
 
    });
});
```

but what now I need to do is connect each bubble with some specific bubbles(as they are related because of  some parameter) using upward arrow(straight lines) and show them when the mouse is hover.
I know it sounds complicated but the idea is simple.

Each bubble is related to some other bubble due to some parameter ,so whenever the user hovers over any bubble it will show up all the connected bubbles using straight line arrow.

Below is the bubble without hover
[bubble without hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcmd1.png)

and this image is a protype of what I am trying to build.[final chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKzTZ.png)

Coming to the problem , I cant find any function or animation on hover to do this task in HighChart. Please guide me for the correct approach.

Comment: So what do you mean by  _Each bubble is related to some other bubble due to some parameter_ . What are the parameters in your added examples you want to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SVGRenderer` to create the paths (connections) in `mouseOver` event:

```
 mouseOver: function() {
  var point = this,
    series = point.series,
    secondPoint = series.points[1],
    chart = series.chart;

  if (!point.index) {
    point.path = chart.renderer.path(['M', chart.plotLeft + point.plotX, chart.plotTop + point.plotY, 'L', chart.plotLeft + secondPoint.plotX, chart.plotTop + secondPoint.plotY])
      .attr({
        stroke: 'red',
        'stroke-width': 2
      })
      .add();
  }

},
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e78xhv6u/

The example shows how to create a single connection between two bubbles. You should extend this demo so that it works for multiple connections. Hiding/destroying the paths can handled in `mouseOut` event.

Comment: Is there a way to get the lines to render behind the circles/starting at the circle's edge? Having the lines on top of the circles is hideous if your circles are a different color than the lines.

Comment: Yes, it is possible of course, you have to compute the appropriate start and end line position. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qhpa7Lz5/1/